# Lvalue object successfully returns from function using conversion constructor with rvalue reference

Tags: c++, return, language-lawyer, c++17, rvalue-reference

The following code [compiles successfully with *g++ 8.3* and *clang 8.0.0*](https://godbolt.org/z/ozr7wc) (compilation flags are `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`)

```
struct Foo
{
};

struct Bar
{
  Bar() = default;

  Bar(Foo&&)
  {
  }
};

Bar baz()
{
  Foo foo;
  return foo;
}

int main()
{
}
```

Is it a bug in this compilers or a requirement of the C++ standard?

Comment: Tell me if there's a problem with the dupe.

Comment: @Mark I don't know why you made this edit, I very deliberately removed the excessive amounts of vertical space because it adds nothing to the question but takes _MUCH LONGER_ to grok it. I understand that people have different preferences in whitespace formatting, but the 10 lines of code I removed add no value - it is making the code example more minimal.

Comment: @Barry "...the 10 lines of code I removed add no value..." → They add `Bar::Bar(Foo&&)` body at least.

Comment: @Constructor ... which isn't relevant to the question. The body of that constructor doesn't affect how overload resolution behaves (and it was empty anyway... )

Comment: @Barry It is relevant because without it the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Barry Edits just to change a reasonable coding style to your favorite style is something that should not be done, especially not if you actually remove code. Furthermore your edit was done after the question was closed, which pollutes the reopen queue. Please refrain from purely cosmetic edits or edits that remove code from a question.

Comment: @Mark I was trying to improve the question. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. But whatever man, you do you.

Comment: @Constructor It absolutely compiles. What it doesn't do is link, but again that's immaterial to the question of how overload resolution works in this situation.